# tabIndex doesn't work on mat-tab (Angular 7)

Tags: angular, tabindex, mat-tab

If i try to use **TAB** (keyboard) to go along the mat-tabs , it doesn't work.
It focuses the current tab and is going in tab content not to the 2nd , 3th tab.

I don't need to show you my code, you can see this behavior on [Tabs | Angular Material Documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview)

How to Reproduce: Left click on ***Basic use of the tab group***, at the 3th TAB press you would end on **First** tab.
[image]

Expected result: Jump to the next tab, not the **Events** title
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was never added to mat-tab because it would affect accessibility. You can use the arrow keys to change selected tabs after tabbing over to the selected tab.

More details on the github feature request listed below:
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11814

Comment: Thank you, I understood why.I didn't knew i can use arrows to navigate yhru tabs